# Hard time understanding relationship data storing using JPA (spring boot)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to know how to store entity in database without storing it's relative as well.

for example you have jobs for workers in your company  and you want to save new jobs into your database.

you create 2 entities Job and Worker with OneToMany relationship ( 1 job for 3 or more workers )

when you save job into database it has field : workers and it must not be null.

**Problem** : when you save job into database it's workers are saved too ! ( jobRepository.save(myJob)

so every time i add new job workers who are already in my database are being added again ( and it breaks application of course because you can not have duplicate workers)

How can i fix this problem? thanks !

example : Job

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Job{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Worker> workers;
}
```

example : Worker

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "workers")
public class User extends DataAudit {

  @Id
  private Long id;


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Job job;

}
```

example : saving job in database

```
Worker worker1 = workerService.getWorkerById(1);
Job job = new Job(1,worker1)

jobRepository.save(job)
```

gives me an error ----> JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation

Comment: You're going to have to show your code. Otherwise it's difficult to deduce what you're doing wrong.

Comment: i added some example code :)

Comment: One thing you could try is for Job#workers you could set the cascade to ALL to ensure it's applying changes like UPDATE.

Comment: Now it gives me this error : optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Comment: User or Worker??

Comment: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [User#2]

Comment: Wait, is the id of each table defined as the PK in the table? Is the id unique (i.e auto-increment)?

Comment: id is unique and auto increments

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicated ids add `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on the id field.

Good luck

Comment: thanks but it still adds workers to a database. i don't want to have duplicate workers for each new job :)

Comment: You could try ```@PrePersist``` or ```@PreUpdate``` and manage the ids manually.